# Which style is more correct for check in javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, instance

I often see JavaScript code which checks for *undefined, null* values in such way:

```
if (typeof input !== "undefined") {
   if ( input != null ) {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

But I thought that it may look too much simple and not elegant, and I want to provide the next piece of code:

```
// just have taken from my own code

setCamera: function( camera, scene, vector3 ) {
    if ( !~[ undefined, null ].indexOf( camera ) && camera instanceof( THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) ) { 
        camera.position.set( vector3 );
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        scene.add( camera );
    }
    else ...
}
```

Isn't such a way of code more good, elegant and useful for check?

```
if ( !~[ values... ].indexOf( inputObject ) &&
     inputObject instanceof( instance ) )
```

Comment: I encourage you to see [Idiomatic Javascript](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/#idiomatic-style-manifesto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `camera` is declared as an argument, referring to it will not give a ReferenceError like you would get if it were completely undeclared.

Therefore, just do this:

```
if( camera instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera)
```

`undefined` and `null` are obviously not instances of the camera, therefore no problems.

Comment: I'm not checking the camera for a instance of null or undefined.
Because it could be: if(typeof сamera == "undefined") //no errors
if(сamera == null) //throws ReferenceError: сamera is not defined

Comment: As I explained in my answer, `camera` IS defined as an argument of the function. It's like if you were to write `camera = undefined; alert(camera);`.

Comment: @GeloVolro: The code will **never** throw a ReferenceError because you defined `camera` as parameter of the function. The variables is *always* declared.

Comment: ah... see, correct! sorry, just have confused something